# Plotly. Size of nodes scaled differently between different sankey diagrams

Tags: python, alignment, plotly, sankey-diagram

I am plotting sankey diagrams with plotly in Python as in: https://plot.ly/~alishobeiri/1591/plotly-sankey-diagrams/#/.

For a single sankey diagram the size of nodes scale such that they fill out the height of the entire diagram. This is an issue when comparing different sankeys as these will be scaled differently. Is there a way to scale the height of the nodes according to a certain value, which then can be used in all sankey plotting. Fx, 1000 corresponds to 1cm. Finally, one will be able to compare sankey nodes from different diagrams just by looking at the size without considering actual nodal values.